# OPC UA Subscriptions and Notifications

Tags: opc, opc-ua

I'm having trouble with OPC UA Subscriptions and Notifications in the ANSI C stack. OPC UA Part 4, Service says:

> 5.13.1 Subscription model
>   5.13.1.1 Description c) NotificationMessages are sent to the Client in response to Publish requests.

Sent how? I'm really expecting a callback of some sort, but there doesn't seem to be one. It does say these are in response to a 'Publish' request, but a Publish service call acknowledges receipt of a notification, it doesn't seem to request one. Besides, that would be polling and the whole point of Subscriptions and Monitoring is to not poll.

Can anyone supply an example showing monitoring of a data value in ANSI C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PublishRequests are queued on the server and responses are only returned when notifications are ready or a keep-alive needs to be sent (or a bunch of other stuff, check the state machine description in part 4).

They do include acknowledgements of previously received notifications as well, but the idea is that the response isn't expected immediately and that the client will generally keep pumping PublishRequests out so that the server has a queue of them ready to return notifications whenever a subscription needs to.

<s>Yes, it's polling. It's a bit of a bummer that it's not strictly unsolicited, but that's how it works.</s>

__

edit:

It's not really polling. It's batched report by exception with a QoS guarantee and back pressure mechanism provided by subsequent PublishRequests.

Comment: OK. That helps. I've switched to the OpcUa_ClientApi_BeginPublish call and am getting one data change event as Sequence 1, and from then on I get empty responses as Sequence 2. Apparently these are the Keep Alive messages.  Now if I could just figure out why I'm not getting the other data change events. It's progress anyway, Thanks.

Comment: Have you created any MonitoredItems yet? and if so, are they configured to report only on value change (the monitoring filter param)?

Comment: Also it sounds like you're just using the stack; when it comes to developer products for UA there seems to be a divide between "stack" and "SDK". What you're trying to do yourself is something that traditionally an SDK would do for you. If you can purchase or find an open source SDK that might accelerate your progress a bit.

Comment: I have monitored items working correctly now. My final stumbling block was understanding the filter criteria and getting the extension object set up correctly. Items are correctly updating and triggering data change events.

Comment: Yes, I am using just the stack, other than getting my head wrapped around a few things it seems to be all I need. I also did all my own COM work with the older OPC interfaces. Just a low level guy.

Comment: @KevinHerron How to implement message queue with Opc Ua?

Answer (score 1):

This is C# code. I hope that it will help you.

```
private NotificationMessageReceivedEventHandler
    m_NotificationMessageReceived;

// ...

m_NotificationMessageReceived = 
    new NotificationMessageReceivedEventHandler
       (Subscription_NotificationMessageReceived);
m_subscription.NotificationMessageReceived +=
    Subscription_NotificationMessageReceived;

// ...

private void Subscription_NotificationMessageReceived
    (Subscription subscription,
     NotificationMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NotificationMessage.NotificationData == null ||
        e.NotificationMessage.NotificationData.Count == 0)
    {
        LogMessage("{0:HH:mm:ss.fff}: KeepAlive",
                   e.NotificationMessage.PublishTime.ToLocalTime());
    }
}
```